# User system - multiple usergroups

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently working on a user system, and would like to setup multiple usergroups/ranks per member.  I see other posts on here explaining it by using foreign keys, denormalized tables, etc... but they're all from 2010-2012, so wasn't sure if there were easier/better standard ways of doing it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `character_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `verify` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `rank` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rank` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rank` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;
```

The above are my two tables.  Here are the two table structures with three examples in each:

`users`
`id | username | password | email | character_name | verify | rank | position`
`1  | userA    | passA    | A@A   | characterA     | yes    | mem  | 1`
`2  | userB    | passB    | B@B   | characterB     | yes    | mod  | 1`
`3  | userC    | passC    | C@C   | characterC     | yes    | adm  | 3`

`rank`
`id | rank   | position`
`1  | mem    | 1`
`2  | mod    | 1`
`3  | adm    | 3`

Users should be able to be in multiple ranks.

userA should only be a mem.
userB should be a mem and mod.
userC should be a mem, mod, and adm.

If I were to join both tables:

```
SELECT * FROM rank INNER JOIN users ON rank.position = users.position;
```

1. Would that cause userA to be mem and mod as well, since the position for both is 1?
2. Would it make more sense to remove rank and position from users, position from rank, and join based on user id?

For example (question 2):

`users`
`id | username | password | email | character_name | verify`
`1  | userA    | passA    | A@A   | characterA     | yes`
`2  | userB    | passB    | B@B   | characterB     | yes`
`3  | userC    | passC    | C@C   | characterC     | yes`

`rank`
`id | rank`
`1  | mem`
`2  | mem`
`2  | mod`
`3  | mem`
`3  | mod`
`3  | adm`

```
SELECT * FROM rank INNER JOIN users ON rank.id = users.id;
```

Once selected, I want certain ranks to be able to do certain things.

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM rank INNER JOIN users ON rank.id = users.id;
$ranks = $conn->query($sql);
$ranks->execute();
foreach ($ranks as $row) {
  if($row['rank'] == "mem" {
    Do something.
  }
  if($row['rank'] == "mod" {
    Do something else.
  }
  if($row['rank'] == "adm" {
    Do another something else.
  }
}
```

3. Is the above correct?

*Edited, because my first posting apparently wasn't clear enough*.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use google and read up on database organization, user systems, and SQL queries. Your first question is entirely dependent on what you plan to do with this database. Denormalization is a speed optimization. Your second and third questions are entirely dependent on what you want your usergroups to do, and you seem confused on how permission systems and foreign keys even work. Your fourth question is asking somebody to write your SQL without any apparent attempt, which is not what SO is for.

Comment: Edited my original request.  You were right, it wasn't specific enough, nor did I provide sufficient explanation/examples of what I wanted.